# Strange syntax used in bootstrap.js tooltip plugin, and calculating tool tip position

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
placement = placement == 'bottom' && pos.top   + pos.height  + actualHeight - docScroll > parentHeight  ? 'top'    :
            placement == 'top'    && pos.top   - docScroll   - actualHeight < 0                         ? 'bottom' :
            placement == 'right'  && pos.right + actualWidth > parentWidth                              ? 'left'   :
            placement == 'left'   && pos.left  - actualWidth < parentLeft                               ? 'right'  :
            placement
```

This is code in bootstrap.js tooltip plugin. The whole can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nettrinity/g8U82/).

Why it ends each line with ":", not ";"?
Can you help me explain the syntax? Also I don't understand the arithmetic. If you know this technique for calculationg if a tool tip should appear left, right, top or bottom of an element, please help me understand it. Thank you!

Comment: It's a `ternary operator`, please google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has the conditional operator `?:` (also called a ternary operator). You can read a description of it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). The general syntax is

> *condition* ? *expr1* : *expr2*

It evaluates *condition* and then either *expr1* if *condition* is `true` or *expr2* if *condition* is `false`. The value of the overall expression is the value of whichever of *expr1* or *expr2* is evaluated.

In the code you posted, there are several nested uses of the conditional operator. Here's a two-level nesting:

```
a ? x : b ? y : z
```

Because of the precedence rules, it is evaluated as if it were written:

```
a ? x : (b ? y : z)
```

For clarity, it is common to not use parentheses and also to introduce line breaks and white space so that the various parts of each conditional operator all line up vertically. For example:

```
r = a ? x :
    b ? y :
    z;
```

This can continue for as many conditions as one likes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ted. I understand a? x:b, but could have challenge putting them toghether.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (actually a chain of).

```
a = b ? c : d
```

is a shorthand for

```
if (b) {
  a = c
} else {
  a = d
}
```

The operator precedence rules enable you to write

```
variable = condition1 ? value1 :
           condition2 ? value2 :          
              .  .  .
           conditionN ? valueN :
           defaultValue
```

instead of N `if`/`else if` statements without using any extra parenthesis.

As usual, you better understand what you are doing, as this operator works differently in other languages, most notably in PHP.